# Collect AdMob statistics from webpage view

Tags: android, statistics, admob

I want to generate, for personal purposes, some statistics related to Admob estimated ernings by hour for each day. More exactly: I would like to have a service which each hour takes the "Estimated earnings" at that hour from apps.admob.com site. I wasn't able to take that value. The page source does not contain that value.

```
class MyJavaScriptInterface {
        public MyJavaScriptInterface(Context ctx) {
        }

        public void processContent(String aContent) {
            final String content = aContent; // this contains the page source which does not contain the info I want
            System.out.println("content: " + content);
        }
    }

    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.addJavascriptInterface(new MyJavaScriptInterface(this), "INTERFACE");
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl("javascript:window.INTERFACE.processContent(document.documentElement.innerHTML);");
        }
    });

    webView.loadUrl("https://apps.admob.com/#home");
```

Is there a way to get that value from the page (maybe even using some automated tools)?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [AdSense Management API](http://developers.google.com/adsense/management/) to get reports on AdSense/Admob earnings.

You can make direct requests,or use the [client libraries and samples](http://developers.google.com/adsense/management/libraries) for your implementation.

[Here is](http://developers.google.com/adsense/management/getting_started) a tutorial on getting started

Comment: Do you know if I can get earnings by hour ?